# Declare Variable of Type Class for Inherited Classes

Tags: kotlin

Probably an easy question

If I have two classes, need to cast them to assign them to their base instance:

```
Class Activity1: AppCompatActivity() {}
Class Activity2: AppCompatActivity() {}

lateinit var toOpen: Class<AppCompatActivity>
```

If I want to do

```
 toOpen = Activity1::class
```

I always get a type mismatch. toOpen is expecting AppOmpatActivity

What is the correct way to do either:

```
 toOpen = Activity1::class // or
 toOpen = Activity2::class
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for

```
lateinit var toOpen : Class<in AppCompatActivity>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting the same error:

lateinit var toOpen : Class<in AppCompatActivity>
toOpen = HomeActivity::class.java. still throws type mismatch

Comment: Did you try without `.java`?

Comment: Yes, I did:

        lateinit var toOpen : Class<in AppCompatActivity> 
        toOpen = HomeActivity::class

Comment: You need to do it *with* `.java`. Otherwise the type is a KClass.